# How to rotate an image around its center point in a JavaScript canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas, typescript

I have this function to get the rotation angle from my sprite and a target:

```
getAngle( spr:Sprite, x:number, y:number ):number
{
    let vx:number = x - ( spr.getX() + spr.w / 2 );
    let vy:number = y - ( spr.getY() + spr.h / 2 );
    let angle = Math.atan2( vy, vx ) * (180 / Math.PI);
    return angle;
}
```

Basically this is:

```
target.x - sprite.centerX;

target.y - sprite.centerY;
```

Then i use **atan2** and multiply by radians. The way I use that angle is:

```
ctx.translate( this.getX() + centerX, this.getY() + centerY );
ctx.rotate( this.angle );
ctx.scale( this.xScale, this.yScale );
ctx.translate( - ( this.getX() + centerX ), -( this.getY() + centerY ) );
```

However, the above is not working. I have been investigating this and it seems to be okay, but it still does not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is [a very similar question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628484/draw-multiple-images-on-canvas-with-each-image-rotated).

Answer (score 1):

after i posted the question i was looking a little deeper, the code seems to work fine, however works if the canvas element has a position of `x:0 & y:0`, so if is in a different place like mine which is centered and has margings/paddings then the coordinates of the canvas are different. to fix this i had to correct `mouseMove.clientX` & `mouseMove.clientY` values not passing them directly:

```
mouseMove(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        let boundingRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        let eX = event.clientX - boundingRect.left;
        let eY = event.clientY - boundingRect.top;
        this.arrowShooter.angle =getAngle(this.arrowShooter, eX, eY);
    }
```

so substracting **left** and top **from** *canvas.getBoundingClientRect()* to **event.clientX/Y** fixed mouse canvas coordinates.